# Checking/Writing lines to a .txt file using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new both to this site and python, so go easy on me. Using Python 3.3

I'm making a hangman-esque game, and all is working bar one aspect. I want to check whether a string is in a .txt file, and if not, write it on a new line at the end of the .txt file. Currently, I can write to the text file on a new line, but if the string already exists, it still writes to the text file, my code is below:

Note that my text file has each string on a seperate line

```
write = 1
if over == 1:
    print("I Win")
    wordlibrary = file('allwords.txt')
    for line in wordlibrary:
        if trial in line:
            write = 0
    if write == 1:
        with open("allwords.txt", "a") as text_file:
            text_file.write("\n")
            text_file.write(trial)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this really the indentation from your program?

As written above, in the first iteration of the loop on wordlibrary,
the trial is compared to the line, and since (from your symptoms) it is not contained in *the first line*, the program moves on to the next part of the loop: since write==1, it will append trial to the text_file.

cheers,
 Amnon

Comment: Hello Amnon, Thanks for the reply.

I made an error in the indentation above, (edited). How can I get the program to compare each and every line in the .txt file? I guess I'd need the number of lines in the .txt file and some way of specifying line = line + 1 in the loop and continuing until the 'line number' is equal to the number of lines in the .txt file? Any help would be appreciated. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to know the number of lines present in the file beforehand. Just use a file iterator. You can find the documentation here : http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

Pay special attention to the readlines method.